# Php css to local storage

Tags: php, local-storage

I have some inline css code in php: (shortened example)

```
#player{
    position:relative;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:900px;
}
#player .drop{
    width:220px;
}
```

Is it possible to send this to local storage so I can get it later with javascript?

Comment: If its applied to an element than you can always get it with JavaScript later.

Comment: My question is how to set it to local storage from php.